# Visualforce Tab Access?

Tags: visualforce, customsetting, permission-sets

**Background**

I have a `List Custom Setting` which I want to expose to a few managers. However, I do not want to give them `Customize Application` permission, so I created a `Visualforce Page` that enables CRUD on this particular setting. To make this page easier to find, I created a `Custom Tab` for it (default hidden). My plan was to control access to both the page and the tab through `Permission Set`, but I cannot figure out a way to expose the tab itself.

**Question**

Is it possible to make a `Visualforce Tab` accessible via `Permission Set`? Is there a smoother way to enable a small group of super-users to edit a specific `Custom Setting`?

Comment: Permission sets can control Tab visibility http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_tab_visibility.htm

Comment: May be you have to check override personal setting box ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I did follow the steps in that link, and it didn't work. The tab doesn't show up in the search results.

Comment: Just added screenshots and answer so it helps .Seems like docs are not that clear .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could find the VF tab in the Object Settings .Its confusing that Tab settings are mixed with Object Settings .

[image]

My sample VF tab showed up

[image]

Here is the Settings

[image]

Comment: I also confused myself by naming the tab the same as the setting, so I thought the setting was what showed up there.

Comment: Ah I see .Anyways glad its fixed :) .Keep rocking .